# Prove that every cyclic group with order n is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z /n\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Here is my proof i would like to get some suggestions please :))

Let G without loss of generality be 
{${a^0,a^1,a^2... a^{n-1}}$}

So what i tried is creating a surjective homomorphism

$ f:\Bbb Z\rightarrow $ $ G $ , $k \rightarrow  a^k$

Then

$ ker(f)$={$n^k | k \in \Bbb Z $}

Using the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms:

$\Bbb Z /n\Bbb Z \cong G$

Comment: Your proof is correct, but since $\mathbb {Z} $ and $ G $ are abelian groups, it should be better to change to the additive notation.

Comment: Any feedback ? What should i do to make the prove more elegant ?

Comment: As Xammm points out, you should write the kernel as $\text{ker }f = \{nk|k \in \Bbb Z\} = n\Bbb Z$.